# Apple Mail hides mail received on multiple addresses

Tags: mail.app

Recently I've noticed that if I'm sent an e-mail on multiple addresses for which I have accounts set up in Apple Mail (macOS or iOS), the Apple Mail client will only display *only one* of these mails, and provide no access (other than explicitly selecting to view one account) to the others. Moreover I can't choose which account's mail is displayed (and it can be different on macOS and iOS).

Is this the intended behavior? Is there a way to restore the normal e-mail client behavior of simply seeing all the mail I've been sent?

Answer (score 1):

Many common Apple mail issues can be fixed by rebuilding the **Envelope Index**.

MAKE SURE YOU HAVE CREATED A BACKUP, FIRST. YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED!

- Quit mail.app
- Hold down the Option key, then in the Finder choose Go > Library.
- In Macintosh HD`/Users/yourname/Library/Mail/V2/MailData`, move all files starting with “Envelope Index,” such as Envelope Index or Envelope Index-shm to your Desktop.
- Launch Mail and it will build new Envelope Index files -- this step could take a long time.

Comment: First question: is this the intended behavior.

Comment: It's not the intended behavior. Sounds like a file corruption issue.

Comment: Are you certain. What file would be corrupted and why on all devices at the same time?